# Suppressing passwd when calling sqlplus from shell script

Tags: oracle, security, sqlplus

My script calls `sqlplus` in the standard format:

```
sqlplus $USER/$PASSWD@$DBNAME
```

Obviously, this is not very safe because `ps -ef` displays the entire command, including the passwd.

How can I invoke sqlplus without a manual prompt but still hide the passwd?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**BAD:**

```
sqlplus $USER/$PASSWD@$SID<<!!

...
--some SQL
...

!!
```

`ps -ef` displays connect string

**GOOD:**

```
sqlplus /nolog<<!!

connect $USER/$PASSWD@$SID;

...
--some SQL
...

!!
```

`ps -ef` does **not** display connect string

Comment: I think I'd characterise them as "Bad" and "Not good" really. It's true that ps -ef does not expose the connect string, but storing user ids and passwords in files is definitely not a good security practice, and at most of the corporations I've worked at is expressly forbidden by IT security policies.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is a different method of authentication, such as the Oracle Wallet.

Here's a walk-through in the documentation.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e16543/authentication.htm#CBHGEBEI